¿Cómo resolver el error: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON at JSON.parse
me gustaría que el usuario pudiera cambiar su clave. Para ello, la idea es obtener el id del usuario actual, y cambiar la clave por la nueva que se envíe, donde el nombre de usuario coincida. Para la parte del back, tengo el siguiente controlador:
@PostMapping("/cambiar-clave")
    public ResponseEntity<Usuario> cambiarClave(@RequestParam Long id, @RequestParam String claveNueva) {
        try {
            Usuario usuarioActualizado = userService.cambiarClave(id, claveNueva);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(usuarioActualizado);
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Mensaje de error: " + exception.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(null);
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/id/{login_name}")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Long>> getUserIdByUserName(@PathVariable String login_name) {
        Usuario usuario = userService.findByUserName(login_name);
        if (usuario == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        } else {
            Map<String, Long> response = new HashMap<>();
            response.put("id", usuario.getId());
            return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
        }
    }

Previamente mapeado con @RequestMapping("/api/users")
Para la parte del front, a la hora de obtener el id, tengo el siguiente método en la clase UsuarioService:
getIdUsuarioActual(login_name: string) {
    const url = `${this.url}/id/${login_name}`;
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        if (response && response.id) {
          return response.id;
        } else {
          throw new Error('La respuesta del servidor no es válida');
        }
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        return throwError('Error al obtener el ID del usuario actual: ' + error.message);
      })
    );
  }

El error que se muestra en la consola del navegador es el siguiente:
cambiar-clave.component.ts:53 Error al obtener el ID del usuario actual: Error al obtener el ID del usuario actual: Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/api/users/id/administrador dado que está recibiendo un HTML cómo respuesta. No sé qué puede estar fallando, o si simplemente el planteamiento está mal. A la hora de hacer una solicitud con Postman, a la url: http://localhost:8080/api/users/id/administrador se devuelve lo siguiente:
{
    "id": 1
}

Tengo además,esto en el servicio para cambiar la clave:
export class ChangePasswordService {
  private url: string = '/api/users'; 

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  changePassword(id: number, newPassword: string): Observable<any> {
    const params = { id: id.toString(), claveNueva: newPassword };
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.url}/cambiar-clave`, null, { headers: headers, params: params });
  }

Y este código HTML:
<div class="container contenedor-formulario">
  <div class="uf-form-signin">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h1 class="titulo" style="font-family: Montserrat;">Cambiar contraseña</h1>
    </div>
    <form class="mt-4 login-form" #changePasswordForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="changePassword(changePasswordForm)">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" ngModel>
      <div class="input-group uf-input-group input-group-lg mb-3">
        <span class="input-group-text fa fa-lock"></span>
        <input type="password" name="newPassword" ngModel class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña nueva" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group uf-input-group input-group-lg mb-3">
        <span class="input-group-text fa fa-lock"></span>
        <input type="password" name="confirmNewPassword" ngModel class="form-control" placeholder="Confirma contraseña" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="d-grid mb-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn uf-btn-primary btn-lg">Aceptar</button>
      </div>
      <div class="d-grid mb-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn uf-btn-primary btn-lg" (click)="volverAHome($event)">Cancelar</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>


¿Revisaste qué te está respondiendo el servidor? Porque así como aparece en el título, te está retornando un HTML.

El método del lado del backend
 @PostMapping("/cambiar-clave")
public ResponseEntity<Usuario> cambiarClave(@RequestBody Usuario usuario) {
    try {
        Usuario usuarioActualizado = userService.cambiarClave(usuario.getId(), usuario.getPassword());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(usuarioActualizado);
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Mensaje de error: " + exception.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(null);
    }
}

El servicio en el frontEnd de actualizar
changePassword = (id: number, newPassword: string) =>{
const params = { id: id.toString(), claveNueva: newPassword };

return this.http.post<any>(`${this.url}/cambiar-clave`, params);}


Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].
